# Select + count разных параметров

Tags: mysql, sql, count, methodscount

Мы имеем 2 столбца в первом Site_ID (любой, но повторяются), во втором Level (0 или 1)

ну и пример
123,0
666,1
967,0
666,0

В итоге хочется получить (Site_id/count(Level=0)/count(Level=1)),
то есть из примера выше мы получим

123,1,0
666,1,1
967,1,0

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать `CASE` внутри `COUNT`

```
SELECT
   Site_id,
   COUNT(CASE Level WHEN 0 THEN 1 END) AS Level_0,
   COUNT(CASE Level WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) AS Level_1
FROM Table
GROUP BY Site_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   Site_id,
   SUM(Level = 0) AS Level_0,
   SUM(Level = 1) AS Level_1
FROM DataTable
GROUP BY Site_id;
```

Comment: пожалуйста, опишите идею, как работает конструкция `SUM(Level = 0)`

Comment: @mymedia В точном соответствии с документацией: `the values TRUE and FALSE are merely aliases for 1 and 0, respectively`.